# Strategy to create a screen resolution independent java desktop application?

Tags: eclipse, swing, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I have been been programming with java using eclipse  for a few months and would consider myself at an intermediate level, and i have a vb.net background originally.

I have a question about screen resolution( in pixels) and auto-scaling my application with two parts

A) When you design a desktop application with swing( or JavaFX ) do you actually calculate the pixel width and height of every single component and then scale it up or down in code by detecting the screen resolution at startup?  Scene-Builder for JavaFX, Eclipse Windows Builder Gridbag layout and GroupLayout  have the facility to do it with a couple of clicks, and it is relatively easy . If it IS calculated and handcoded then that means I'll have to spend a lot of time planning ahead for each control.

B) Is there a common consensus over a screen resolution ( 1024x768 e.g.) to design the application for "initially" ( and then scaling all controls according to detected screen resolution)? My monitor has 1920x1080 resolution but I am confused which resolution should i begin designing my application in. 1024x768 seems reasonable to me.

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done all my work in Java Swing, so this might not be appropriate for other GUI sets.

- Layout all the components within panels and one frame.
- Pack the frame.
- Print out the size of the frame.
- If the frame is too big, put some components in a scroll pane.
- Repeat until the frame is the desired size.

In other words, I'm concerned with the functionality of the GUI.  I don't care how big it is, unless it's too big for a display.

I put together an alarm clock that has a frame of 170 x 152 pixels.  It sits in the lower right hand corner of my display.

[image: Alarm Clock]

I put together a clock / calendar that has a frame of 1097 X 522 pixels.  It sits in the upper right hand corner of my display.

[image: Clock/calendar]

I put together a Cobol Paragraph Structure display where I maximized the frame to the size of the display, mainly so the paragraph name tree had the maximum amount of space.

[image: Cobol Paragraph Structure]

Comment: Oh +1 for a Swing based answer and use of Cobol :-)

Comment: Thanks. but that doesnt answer either part 1 or part 2 of the question at all I'm afraid.???

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it: 1) No.  2) No.